# Get sum of x_i and x_i+1

Tags: sql

I have a table with segment id, x and y coordinate
I need to get the length of the segment.
How can I get the length using something like this:

```
(x1 + x2)*(x1 + x2) + (y1 + y2)*(y1 + y2)
```

Table example is in the picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAUw7.png

Comment: Try to give the full context of your question and explain what you have tried. In your case, I understand you are looking for a SQL query? What DB are you using? Have you tried something already? By the way, your formula is wrong.

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `group by` as follows:

```
select segment_id, 
       sum(x)*sum(x) + sum(y)*sum(y) as ln
  from t
 group by segment_id
```